# Epub Resources for 3.0 - Where the best place to learn?

Tags: epub3

Does anyone know any really good resources for learning about coding epub 3.0.   Particularly for fixed layout epub?
These are the ones I have been using so far
https://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/wiki/SamplesListing#sous-le-vent  http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#elemdef-meta
https://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/downloads/list
Where is best to go for learning about epub 3 or to get help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found the best learning about EPUB3 can be found below:
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-richlayoutepub/index.html

Enjoy EPUB3!!!

Answer (score 1):

The most useful resource i have found so far is definitely Liz Castro's blog: http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/.

She has a ton of great examples, tutorials and downloads!

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. hopefully it will help me.

Comment: Cool, if it does you should upvote!

Comment: sorry dude, i haven't got enough reputation to upvote and i was hoping to get more answers from ppl so there was a full list for people who need this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is good for learners:

1. It gives Introduction
2. Changes in EPUB3
3. Validating EPUB 3 documents
   [Link1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-richlayoutepub/)

Gitden reader is good to use for EPUB3

Some offline debug you can download 
[Pagina Epub checker](http://www.pagina-online.de/produkte/epub-checker/)